# dummy variable in R, results in all 0

Tags: r, dummy-variable

could you please help identify where I make an error creating dummy variable for state. I am trying to assign 1 to states "New York, New Jersey, California, and Illinois" and 0 to the rest of the states in the data set. Somehow I end seeing "0" only in the dataset. Ultimately, I am creating this dummy to calculate DID. Thank you for your help!

```
str(counties)
counties$date <- as.Date(counties$date, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
#create dummy variables forNew York, New Jersey, California, and Illinois
counties$state = ifelse(counties$state == 'New Jersey' & 
               counties$state == 'New York'& counties$state == 'California' & 
               counties$state == 'Illinois', 1, 0)
counties$dummy <- as.integer(counties$date >= as.Date('2020-04-11'))
head(counties)
str(counties)

# Compute the four data points needed in the DID calculation:
a = sapply(subset(counties, dummy == 0 & state == 0, select=cases), mean)
b = sapply(subset(counties, dummy == 0 & state == 1, select=cases), mean)
c = sapply(subset(counties, dummy == 1 & state == 0, select=cases), mean)
d = sapply(subset(counties, dummy == 1 & state == 1, select=cases), mean)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)

# Difference in difference parameter
(d-c)-(b-a)
```

result of my code

```
> head(counties)
        date    county state  fips cases deaths dummy
1 2020-01-21 Snohomish     0 53061     1      0     0
2 2020-01-22 Snohomish     0 53061     1      0     0
3 2020-01-23 Snohomish     0 53061     1      0     0
4 2020-01-24      Cook     0 17031     1      0     0
5 2020-01-24 Snohomish     0 53061     1      0     0
6 2020-01-25    Orange     0  6059     1      0     0
> str(counties)
'data.frame':   218627 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ date  : Date, format: "2020-01-21" "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23" ...
 $ county: Factor w/ 1774 levels "Abbeville","Acadia",..: 1468 1468 1468 379 1468 1178 379 1468 979 942 ...
 $ state : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fips  : int  53061 53061 53061 17031 53061 6059 17031 53061 4013 6037 ...
 $ cases : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ deaths: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dummy : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> print(a)
   cases 
96.10503 
> print(b)
cases 
  NaN 
> print(c)
   cases 
450.3478 
> print(d)
cases 
  NaN
```

Comment: use OR  `|` in stead of AND `&` within your `ifelse()`, and/or take a look at `%in%`

Comment: Or simply ifelse(counties$state %in% c('New Jersey', 'New York', 'California', 'Illinois'), 1, 0)